# How to detect key press when the console window has lost focus

Tags: python, winapi, msvcrt

My application sends a mouse click to an area of the screen outside my console window using `win32api.mouse_event`.  This causes my window to lose focus so I can't detect key presses using `msvcrt.kbhit.`

My question is, how to implement something like this with the console window not being visible/active?

EDIT:

Here is example code. This is just a basic console version. If the console disappears, set it so that it stays on top. Once it clicks outside of the console (100,100), pressing the Esc key will not break out of loop. How would one implement a break for a problem such as this?

```
import msvcrt, win32api, win32con

pixelx = 100
pixely = 100

win32api.SetCursorPos((pixelx,pixely))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,pixelx,pixely,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,pixelx,pixely,0,0)

while 1:
    print 'Testing..'
    # body of the loop ...
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        if ord(msvcrt.getch()) == 27:
            break
```

Comment: Show your code.  We can't guess what's wrong with it without seeing it.

Comment: there we go, sorry about that :/

Answer (score 7):

I can see 3 possible ways of doing this. The first, would be to bring your window to the top after the mouse click, however I assume this is not what you want to happen.

A second way, which should work fine if all you want is the ESC key, would be to use a hotkey. This could be done using a method similar to this:

```
import win32con, ctypes, ctypes.wintypes

def esc_pressed():
    print("Escape was pressed.")

ctypes.windll.user32.RegisterHotKey(None, 1, 0, win32con.VK_ESCAPE)

try:
    msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
    while ctypes.windll.user32.GetMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg), None, 0, 0) != 0:
        if msg.message == win32con.WM_HOTKEY:
            esc_pressed()
        ctypes.windll.user32.TranslateMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))
        ctypes.windll.user32.DispatchMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg))
finally:
    ctypes.windll.user32.UnregisterHotKey(None, 1)
```

For more information on registering a hotkey with Python you can look [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/catch_system_wide_hotkeys.html).

The third way, which you would have to use if you wanted to catch every key press, would be to set a low level keyboard hook.

Answer (score 2):

May be this one will work.

```
import win32api
while True:
     state = win32api.GetKeyState(117)  #F6
     while state:
          state = win32api.GetKeyState(117)
          #do something
```

If you press F6, even the console is not visible, the script will stop, then resume when you press F6 one more time.
Hope this help!