# How to send “shift+F11” with telnet in python

Tags: python-2.7, ascii, telnetlib

I have to send <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> key to `telnet host(tn5250)`, how do I send it using python?

For example, to send <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, I am using this sequence of characters `\x1B[25~`

I know there is some logic involved in conversion of keyboard's keys to ASCII characters. Can someone give me a link or details to gain knowledge in this area?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that "\x1B[25~" char sequence is for "Shift+F1" or is it for "Shift+F3"?

Comment: Yes it translate to "Shift+F1" on my machine.

Comment: http://brebru.com/asciicodes.html

Comment: http://www.geocities.jp/sakachin2/xehelp/html/HID00000594.htm

Comment: see if you can implement a key hook:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767387/detect-shift-key-presses-with-python-ctypes

Comment: The code listed at http://www.geocities.jp/sakachin2/xehelp/html/HID00000594.htm is not working, I think it for "vt100" and mine is "tn5250". 

About http://brebru.com/asciicodes.html I think the code "135" should be used with proper escape sequence. But I tried "\x1B135", "\x1B0135", "\x1B[0x135","\x135"...but not working.